# How to access element from an object? java

Tags: java, object, constructor

I'm new to programming and I'm currently starting with java. I was wondering how to access elements of an object that I created. I thought I knew how but it doesn't seem to work. I'm constructing an object inside an inner class from a method, not in the inner class. I was wondering if you could give me some hints why it is not working when I want to access the values of the object that was just created. I mean can access the values, but they should be different from 0. It's as if my constructor didn't pass back the values. I did put my program in debugging and the values that are passed to the constructor are 0 , 2, 2. Thank you.

```
public class puzzle{

       public class Build{

             int nb, piece, length;

             public Build(int nb, int piece, int length){
                   //In debug I see that the values are passed, but when I print in the method the values printed are all 0.
                   nb = nb;
                   piece = piece;
                   length = length;
}

}
   public void rectangle(String book){
   
         //line of code where I do manipulations

         Build box = new Build(beginning, tv, book.length());

        System.out.println(box.nb);  
        System.out.println(box.piece); //should print a value different then 0
        System.out.println(box.length); //should print a value different then 0


}

}
```

Comment: If you are not using an IDE already i would recommend doing so to write your code. A good IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse would have given you a warning on the line `nb = nb` telling you that `The assignment to variable nb has no effect`, which would have probably given you a hint of what is going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `nb = nb;`

This doesn't do anything. It sets nb to itself.

You have 2 completely, utterly unrelated variables here. One is called `int nb;` and is a field of your `Build` class. The other is a method parameter, by total coincidence also named `nb`.

You want to set the field, with the parameter value.

You have two options.

1. Stop using the same name. The method param 'takes precedence' (in java parlance: Shadows the field).
2. Use `this.nb` which refers to the field: `this.nb = nb;`.

The second form is idiomatic java. Do that.